Hexagon tiling and affine Weyl group $\widetilde{A}_2$
Let $H$ be a regular hexagonal room centered at the origin. Let $W$ be the group generated by reflections about the six sides of $H$. It's well known that $W$ is the affine Weyl group of type $\widetilde{A}_2$. Moreover, $H$ tiles the entire plane under the action of $W$ (though 6 group elements in $W$ can map $H$ to a same room).
Let $H'$ be any regular hexagon room in the tiling, $p$ be a point in $H$, and $q$ be a point in $H'$, then the line segment $pq$ gives an element $w\in W$ such that $wH=H'$. This is because, suppose the line segment $pq$ crosses sequentially through the walls $l_1,\dotsc,l_m$ in the tiling, then we can fold $H'$ back to $H$ by successively reflecting $H'$ about $l_m$, then $l_{m-1}$, and so on. In summary, a line segment joining two rooms gives a word $w\in W$ such that $w$ maps one room to the other.
However, not every $w$ such that $wH=H'$ can correspond to a line segment joining $H$ and $H'$ in the way decribed above. For example, if we reflect $H$ around one of its corners three times, we will get a word $w\in W$ that maps $H$ to itself. But such $w$ certainly does not correspond to a segment that joins $H$ to itself.

My question is, what is the necessary and sufficient condition for $w \in W$ to correspond to a line segment connecting $H$ and $wH$?

In your picture, is there a reason that one of the three arrows goes through a vertex, rather than the midpoint of a wall?

The positioning of the arrows is determined by the following rule: I put a rotated "L" mark at the center of those triangles, and draw an arrow from a mark to another, if the former is reflected to the latter. So the arrows are not meant to pass a vertex or the middle points of the edges. they just point from marks to marks.

A related question that has a easier answer and is very Coxeter-theoretically natural:  Instead tile the plane with equilateral triangles.  The set of reflections in your tiling is the same.  Every group element is obtained from a segment, recording which triangle edges are crossed rather that which hexagon edges.  That is because elements in the group correspond in a natural way to the triangles.  (Declare one triangle $T$ to correspond to the identity element.  Every other triangle is $wT$ for a unique element of the group.)  It may be that the triangles are relevant to your question.

Yes, the situation with the triangular grid issimpler. Furthermore, any line segment connecting two given rooms gives a reduced representation of $w$, because it is a line segment can only cross any hyperplane once.

Precisely how is "a line segment corresponding to a word" (in the generators of the group W) defined?
